# Best Practices to run and schedule Python Scripts on Google Cloud (no Cloud Function)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm building an ETL process that use Firestore and BigQuery. I also write 2 Python scripts: the first one get data from external service and write them to BigQuery, the second one write data from BigQuery to Firestore. I cannot deploy this scripts as Cloud Function (or Cloud Run) due to the timeout limit (9 and 60 minute).
My goal is deploy the two scripts separatley (keeping the Cloud Function logic), schedule the first one daily and start the second one after the first has ran and written data to BigQuery.

Following
https://towardsdatascience.com/the-easiest-way-to-run-python-in-google-cloud-illustrated-d307c9e1651c I deploy a containerized python script to Compute Engine, but is not easy schedule and syncronize the 2 scripts. I could Scheduling a VM instance to start and stop (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop) but I don't know when the first script finish. I could write some cloud functions to start and stops instance based on pub/sub messages (https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule) but it doesn't seem like the cleanest way.

Cloud Scheduler in addition with App Engine or Kubernetes Engine should be the best way to do this works, but I have to start from scratch with GAE or GKE and they seem suitable for application more complex then mine.

Do you have a solution that combine speed of development, clean of process and cost reduction?

Comment: If I am hearing you correctly ... at the highest level you have scheduled based logic that is working with data where you want to express your transformation logic in Python.  This is just screaming Apache Airflow to me.  The corresponding Google product is "Cloud Composer" which is managed Apache Airflow.

Comment: @Kolban first choiche is where deploy scripts. You say to deploy on Compute Engine?

Comment: my suggestion is that from the the description of what it is you want to achieve ... take a look at the product called Cloud Composer which is Googles managed version of Apache Airflow.  Read the overview of "what" Apache Airflow does and then re-read your description of what you want to achieve.  I think you'll see a very close match based on what you have described in your posting.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you said you have to start from scratch with GAE. You already have your python code. You can most likely easily move over to GAE Flexible or GAE Standard (if you're running Python 3). I mention Flexible & Standard for Python3 because those are not tightly coupled to Google internal APIs. Flexible is still limited to 60 minutes but you should look into Task Queues for Flexible and see if it has a longer running time